# Connected web part showing no data

Tags: web-part, connected-web-parts

I have a parent list for which I've created a custom DispForm.
In the custom form, I have added a list which contains child records.
If I connect the web parts and set the provider field and consumer fields, I get no results for the child list.
This same process works fine on the default dispform for the parent list but the layout is not what I want.

Anyone else come across this?